# Php cron job dont work if php-cli was used instead of php

Tags: php, cron

I have set a php cron file to run in a specific time, the specifics of how the cron was set to run was made using the hosting ui and not set using the command line.

If I ran this on my ssh session, in my terminal it'll work

```
/usr/php/54/usr/bin/php-cli /home/user/cron/job.php --arg1="argument1" --arg2="argument2"
```

It'll work, flawlessly, but once I used it as a cronjob, it won't work. Same code command as above won't work

But if I used `php` instead of `php-cli`, it'll work as a cron, but I cannot pass arguments like so:

```
/usr/php/54/usr/bin/php /home/user/cron/job.php
```

What do you think is happening?

Comment: Not sure, but if the second works as a cron, you might want to just try accessing arguments with http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php or use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php

Comment: The title of this question suggests the opposite problem to the one in the content. Are both accurate?

Comment: i am using `getopt`, `php-cli` will accept arguments while `php` wont

Answer (score 0):

You shoul be able to just do:

```
php /home/user/cron/job.php --arg1="argument1" --arg2="argument2"
```

and make sure it's executable

```
sudo chmod +x /home/user/cron/job.php
```

Comment: this won't work, `php` alone does not accept arguments like that

Comment: @JoeySalacHipolito are you sure the script is executable

Comment: @JoeySalacHipolito try `php /home/user/cron/job.php "argument1" "argument2"`